# Cannot Understand one-line code in Leetcode 250 Solution

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree

I have problems in understanding the solution in LeetCode 250. The questions is "Given a binary tree, count the number of uni-value subtrees. A Uni-value subtree means all nodes of the subtree have the same value." The link of the question is https://leetcode.com/problems/count-univalue-subtrees/.

I have attached the solution. I cannot understand the code. What does this line mean?

```
is_uni = self.is_uni(node.left) and is_uni and node.left.val == node.val
```

The Full Solution is

```
class Solution:
def countUnivalSubtrees(self, root):
    if root is None: return 0
    self.count = 0
    self.is_uni(root)
    return self.count

def is_uni(self, node):
    if node.left is None and node.right is None:
        self.count += 1
        return True
    is_uni = True
    if node.left:
        is_uni = self.is_uni(node.left) and is_uni and node.left.val == node.val
    if node.right:
        is_uni = self.is_uni(node.right) and is_uni and node.right.val == node.val
    self.count += is_uni
    return is_uni
```

Comment: that means the value of `is_uni` is dependent on the evaluation of the condition  `self.is_uni(node.left) and is_uni and node.left.val == node.val`

Answer (score 0):

So the line of code you have mentioned, namely

```
is_uni = self.is_uni(node.left) and is_uni and node.left.val == node.val
```

This line of code is recursively calling the class member function `is_uni()` (`self.some_member_function()` is the syntax python uses to access the member variables and functions of the current instance of the class. It is similar to the `this` statement in C, C++ etc) and the baisc logic of this line is that you want to check if the left subtree rooted at `node.left` is a uni-value tree and that the value of `is_uni` is `True` and that the value of the left node `node.left.val` is the same as that of the current `node` being checked.

Now this logic would be repeated until you reach the end of the left sub-tree rooted at `node.left`. Similar logic for checking if the right sub-tree rooted at `node.right` is a uni-value tree and that its value `node.right.val` is the same as the current `node`. These 2 recursive calls are initiated till all the nodes of the tree are checked.

Hope this helps! If you need further clarification, let me know in the comments.